# Java failed to write Core Dump when playing FTB Unleashed

Tags: java, minecraft, coredump

I started to play Minecraft with the Modpack "FTB Unleashed" on a Server I am hosting on Nitrado.com.

When I am playing the game, it always crashes with the Error

```
A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:

EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000006c3d4697, pid=6904, tid=9768

JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_51-b16) (build 1.8.0_51-b16)
Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.51-b03 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
Problematic frame:
V  [jvm.dll+0x4e4697]

Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows

If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
```

As the whole Log is over 400 lines long, I posted it on Pastebin:

```
https://pastebin.com/aQniw4FZ
```

I even updated my Java Version, I only have x64, no x86, and there are no multiple versions installed

Comment: "I even updated my Java Version" No you didn't. That message clearly shows that you're on 1.8.0_51, but the latest Java 8 is 1.8.0_231. Actually update your Java version and see if it fixes it.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I replaced the whole runtime folder with the one in my Minecraft-Installation, which has the version 1.8.0_231, but it still crashes after about 2 hours

Comment: Please post the new crash report.